# require is not defined in a new js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, require, anime.js

**I want to use anime.js.**
For install this library i need to do this:

- $ npm install animejs --save
- const anime = require('animejs');

I want to writte the code in a js file named "anime.js"

**This is "anime.js"**

```
const anime = require('animejs');

anime({
    targets: '.animeTest',
    translateX: 250,
    rotate: '1turn',
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    duration: 800
});
```

**and this is app.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

//EJS Layouts
const  expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts')

//EJS
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'))


app.use(expressLayouts)

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('inicio')
})

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log('Servidor iniciado. Puerto: 3000')
})
```

**The problem is that when i run the program it tells me**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at anime.js:1:15
```

Comment: where is you `anime.js` file used? what do you mean by "run the program"? animejs is a  library for browser animation is it not? `require` from `node_modules` in browser code won't work - you'll need some sort of "build" environment to package your JS for the browser - not sure why you show expressjs code, since that has nothing to do with the browser

Comment: it is called in ejs file: <script type="module" src="./anime.js"></script> that file is in a folder named "views" outside public folder. with "run the program" i just mean when i start the server by console.

Comment: with `type="module"` you'd use import/export for a start, not nodejs' "require" - and if you're getting that error in the server console, you're trying to use a browser library in nodejs - which won't work, since nodejs doesn't have a DOM for a start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I used animejs as a library for a group project, we just included it in the index.html before any other scripts we were trying to run.

Here is the script. Just make sure to include it either in the head with all the meta tags, or somewhere in the body before any of the other scripts you are trying to run.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js" integrity="sha512-z4OUqw38qNLpn1libAN9BsoDx6nbNFio5lA6CuTp9NlK83b89hgyCVq+N5FdBJptINztxn1Z3SaKSKUS5UP60Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: If you have a build environment you could import it as a module as well, but unless you are making this with react, angular, or vue, I'm pretty sure you will want to do it this way. Kind of like you would do when using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS and the browser are very different environments. In NodeJS, you can import CommonJS modules by using `require`, just as you did. But if you want to run the same code in the browser, you need to use a Bundler. It is true that modern browsers now [support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) `import`/`export` syntax, which is the new standard for both Node and the browser, but overall it is recommended to bundle all of the files into one.

For your case, if you want an easy solution to your problem and don't want to deal with complicated configuration files, you can try [Parcel](https://parceljs.org) and keep roughly the same code. Simply navigate to your project directory, and run the following:

```bash
$ npx parcel build anime.js
```

Then simply replace your script with the new, bundled file.